# Cannot send PNG via express route

Tags: node.js, image, express, npm, sharp

I have an png image which I am serving from my express endpoint, the image should be readable as an image source. I have currently got the image as a buffer in node and I am trying to render it however I cannot seem to get the image to appear.

**Outcome**

[image: Outcome of code]

**Expected**

[image]

**Express JS Code**

```js
publicController.get('/avatar', async (req, res, next) => {
  const image = await PUBLIC.avatar();
  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png',
      'Content-Length': image.toString("binary").length
    });
  res.charset = 'binary';
  res.write(image.toString("binary"));
  res.end()
})
```

**Tried Methods:**

- Piping from a readable stream
- Convert to base 64 and render
- Convert to binary and pipe
- Convert to binary and render
- Dump raw png file

**Considerations:**

- I have checked and the PNG file is correct, I created a file from the buffer and the PNG renders perfectly.
- The png image is dynamic dependant on several factors hence why I cannot place in an object storage like s3.

Comment: is `image` a result of .toBuffer()? because there is no .toString() in `sharp`

Answer (score 1):

```
res.write(image.toString("binary"));
```

This isn't appropriate.  If you have a buffer already, don't convert it.  Write it out immediately.

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'image/png',
  'Content-Length': image.length;
});
res.end(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```js
// assuming image is a Buffer
  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png' // drop Content-Length as it should be automatically added by express
    });
  res.end(image);
```

Comment: Express shouldn't calculate `Content-Length`... it should send in chunked transfer mode instead in that case.